# mysql structure based on date

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I was asked to make a module for a storage website, which will display users storage.

There is an application on server which does all of this and has a database, so programmer told me that he can update mysql database whenever change happens to the original one.

He gave me table like this one

```
Balance, date - 13.05.2014

    Warehouse:  21              60,000.00

    №   Name                Quantity    Unit (weight)   Netto

    1   Chicken (15 kg)     4,000   Box (15 kg.)        60,000.00

    Total:      4,000       60,000.00
```

And told me that he will be updating database with sending how much is added or subtracted to the quantity.

In my mind this will look like this

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1000, 0, datetime())
```

where first value is quantity added, second is subtracted and third date.

This is because customer will need to see how many products he had yesterday or maybe 3 month ago

So i need suggestions how to design such database, which will be also performance efficient. Do I really need "two table" structure or can I go with one?

Comment: Hint: Before You decide on an approach, figure out how your coworker arrived at the numbers he gave you... Nudge: 1 Chicken/box and 4,000 Boxes.  If each chicken weighs 15kg, how do you arrive at 60,000??

Comment: he can update those numbers himself

Comment: Yes, using a formula hes trying to get you to Figure out... The numbers are irrelevant, if you can determine the formula

Comment: So I cant structure this database (at least for demo purposes) before knowing the structure?

Comment: To determine the structure, you'll need to determine the formula.  Hint 2: Assume the weight of an item is the weight in the box.  Hint 3: One of your Columns will be a Calculated Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assure you, this developer doesn't hate you.  I can also assure you that the developer has given you all the facts needed to construct a valid table, as I did it using just the facts you gave me.  You must assume a few facts and a formula:

1. The Weight of the item is equal to the Weight of the Box.
2. Since the Box, and the item weight are now the same, the size of the item is irrelevant.
3. Total Weight = Unit Weight * Quantity

**FACT**: The only way the chicken and the box can weigh the same amount is if the chicken is inside the box, therefore the box weighs 0 when empty.
**FACT 2**: Knowing the weight of the box is zero determines the calculation to use.  Since the weight of the box is zero, your developer is using a straightline method to calculate the net total because there is no interference from the box.
**FACT 3**: You can safely use the formula above to calculate any weight with any quantity.  If the box had weight, the formula would be:

Total Weight = (Unit Weight * Quantity) + (Quantity * WeightOfEmptyBox), assuming that only 1 item fits in the box.

**ANSWER**

```
CREATE TABLE WeightOnHand
(
    ProductID INT CONSTRAINT pk_products_pid PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName VARCHAR(25),
    UnitWeight FLOAT,
    Quantity SMALLINT,
    NetTotalWeight AS Quantity * UnitWeight,
    OrderDate As Date
);
GO
```

Also note that this solution has nothing to do with the date.  The date is the only way the developer can give you the information to display it, and to update it, like so:

```
UPDATE WeightOnHand
SET Quantity= 2500
WHERE ProductID = 1 OR OrderDate >='2014-05-23'
```

I have now set the quantity of chickens to 2500.  Your NetTotal will now be 37,500

**UPDATE** The date item is only feasible if you run a report everyday, or you want to store new quantities each day.  To do so, you would update the OrderDate Daily, and then use:

```
SELECT ProductName, Quantity, NetTotalWeight
WHERE OrderDate >=5/23/2014 AND OrderDate <= 5/24/2014
```

`pk_products_pid` is a Primary Key